# How to update to ios 14

Tags: iphone, ios

How do i restore my phone from the beta version back to the original ios 14 version. Fyi. The profile and management option isn’t in my phone anymore for some reason

Answer (score 1):

You can’t downgrade iOS and keep your content and settings and applications. You would need to connect it to a Mac with Finder or PC with iTunes and restore it which erases everything.